# How to export from SQL Server using SSIS - Excel Destination - into an existing excel table

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm having trouble exporting some data from SQL server (Azure) into an existing excel table using SSIS.

Using the SSIS component "Excel Destination" and pointing at the sheet containing the table, SSIS is loading the data in the row below the table (so, headers are on row 1, empty table line on row 2, and the data is placed on rows 3:xxx).

I can point "Excel Destination" at a new sheet, and the data loads into row 1, but I've macros to fire in the same SSIS package, and these require the data in the table.

It would be possible for me to macro the data into the table from this new sheet, but that seems like a pointless extra step. Would anyone be so kind as  to tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure i understand the problem, but are you simply saying that the data starts loading at row 2, not row 3?

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, the table has headers in row 1, and an empty table line in row 2 that i WANT the data to start loading into, but instead, the data loads into the first empty row, which is row 3, and which is not contained within the table - if that helps clarify?

Comment: Try, instead, declaring your range using the SQL Command Data access mode. So, something like `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:AC];` (obviously you need to replace the sheet name and range) and ensure that your destination Excel Connection has *"First row has column names*" ticked, and then check. If it's still "skipping" the row 2, then it's not actually skipping; your first row of data is empty.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, unfortunately my SSIS skill level of 'stumbles through' isn't quite cutting it right now & I'm struggling to implement your solution I'm afraid... Messages and errors include _'No column information was returned by the SQL command'_, and my inability to see the option to enable _'First Row has column headings'_ in the excel destination component. The code I've failed with is: `SELECT       *
FROM            [RawData$A1:H1]` - I've been unable to accurately mention the table name _tblData_